# Qt QML: What's the exact meaning of the property of enabled of Connections

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I am currently using Qt 5.8.0 64bit on VS2015, Windows 10 64bit. According to the doc, the type `Connections` has gained a new property as `enabled` since 5.7.0. The doc says:

> This property holds whether the item accepts change events.

I guess this property controls whether the connections are valid, right? However, when I turn off this property, and the connections are still working! Demo code is listed below:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Button{
        id: button
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: 100
        height: 50
        text: "Click!"
    }

    Connections{
        target: button
        enabled: false
        onClicked:{
            console.log("button Clicked!");
        }
    }
}
```

"button Clicked!" is still running out from the debug output! What's the exact meaning of the property "enabled"?

**P.S.:** it turns out if I set "enabled" as true (the default value is also true), and turn it off `Component.onCompleted`, the connections become invalid and the debug console won't print "button Clicked!" anymore when clicking the button:

```
ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Button{
        id: button
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: 100
        height: 50
        text: "Click!"
    }

    Connections{
        id: connections
        target: button
        enabled: true
        onClicked:{
            console.log("button Clicked!");
        }
    }
    Component.onCompleted: connections.enabled = false;
}
```

Is it a bug?

Comment: With the behavior described, it seems to be a bug. I never used this feature, as you can set the target to `null` to deactivate the `Connections`.

Comment: Yeah, I used to control the connections as you said. However, "enabled", if it works, seems much more meaningful and self-explained than setting target to be `null`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you have stumbled upon a bug, the initial value of the `enabled` property is ignored. `enabled` is only taken into account if the value is changed after the `Connections` item has been completely initalized. Therefore your `Component.onCompleted` trick is a nice workaround.

I have fixed the issue at https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/194840/.